# Can a parameter with the same name as class field cause issues? C#

Tags: c#, class, parameters

I have a class that contains a method of which parameter name matches a field name.

```
class Test 
{
    private int num;

    public void Setup(int num)
    {
        if (num == 10)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any case in which evaluation inside the method Setup, could instead of the parameter, use the field instead?

Comment: Yes, refer to it as `this.num` rather than just `num`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no possibility that an evaluation would use the field instead of the parameter.  Variables within a scope always shadow variables of outer scopes.

So, if your method has a `num` parameter, there is no way to access the instance member `num` from within that method without qualifying it with `this`.

But it is best to try and avoid these situations, if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, refer to it as `this.num` rather than just `num`.

```
class Test 
{
    private int num;

    public void Setup(int num)
    {
        if (num == 10) //parameter
        {
            this.num = 42; //field
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer assumes that the OP is asking how to access a field when there is also a parameter with the same name, but that's not what the OP is asking.   The OP is asking whether having them both could potentially cause problems. (So, look at the difference between your answer and my answer.)

Comment: @MikeNakis - I read the question the other way around that he wants to know how to access the field. The way you're suggesting didn't make sense to me that the OP would be asking that.

Comment: Yes, I know, your reading of the question is not unreasonable, but I think that the "Can [...] cause issues?" part in the title gives it away.  So, for me downvoting you was a way to give my answer a chance, (since yours had already been upvoted, but I considered it off-mark,) and apparently there is one more person who agrees with me.

Comment: @MikeNakis - Fair enough. I guess the OP will let us know.

Comment: it seems like it was settled. C-:=